# Handling authentication in iOS apps

Tags: ios, iphone, authentication

I am trying to figure out the best UX for handling 'protected' view controllers throughout an iOS app, that require authentication. For example, say certain view controllers require authentication in my app. If a user navigates to that view controller I can have a check in viewWillAppear that checks if a user is authenticated and show the login screen if they are not. But here is the tricky part... What happens if they cancel the login? A whole set of issues can arise. I can pop the view controller they are on, but what if the previous controller they came from also requires authentication. I can potentially end up with a chain of popping view controller and showing a login view... This seems like an awful user experience.

I can think of one solution which is working now but doesn't seem correct:

1. An unauthenticated user enters a 'protected' view controller
2. Replace the AppDelegate's window.rootViewController with the login screen
3. When the user logs in successfully they are brought to the first screen of the app (losing the state of where they were in the app).

I assume that this is a common problem that other devs have faced. I couldn't find any best practices for handling this and figured you guys would be able to recommend some tips?

Answer (score -1):

Add a flag in Login view controller that you are coming to the protected view controller from Login View and set that flag to YES when user clicks cancel button on login screen and use popToRootViewController to pop to root view controller. and in rootViewController's viewWillAppear, set flag to NO.

User doesn't need the other protected view controllers if they select cancel in login.

and as per my observation, user doesn't have a chance to go to multiple protected view controllers at once, because, if user comes to first protected view controller, you are showing him login screen and if he cancels it, you are pop ing the view. So there is no chance for user though. either way, the above method works for you.